# WPF Layout is slow in .NET 4.7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an application that is hosted into another application from another company in several versions.  My software has a core module that runs most of the business logic and is the same exact module in all supported versions; this module is built against .NET 4.5.  In this module I have a dialog along with the supporting classes that displays information to the user.

The host software is built on .NET 4.5, 4.5.2, and 4.7 depending on the version of their software.

Now here is the issue.  When it's running inside the software that runs on .NET 4.7 the expansion of a tree node on the main tree of the dialog is MUCH slower than when it's running inside the versions that run on .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.5.2.  Again, this is the exact same code from the exact same module and that module is compiled against .NET 4.5 in all cases.

Why would this be so much slower?  I profiled it and it looks like about 98% of the time on this 71 second profiling segment is in WPF layout measure and arrange methods.

Can anyone shed some light on why this would be so drastically different between versions?

[image]